# How can I make an element disappear?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to hide an element as soon as it becomes visible (has loaded).

I have tried using `timeout` and `setInterval`. They work fine but they are a few seconds late. So first the element loads and then it disappears.
But I want it so it doesn't appear at all and just disappears without appearing first.

I tried to change the time and make it more/less but it didn't help. Is there another way?

I even tried to put the timeout and `setinterval` inside `window.load` it didn't work. I also tried checking when the element is visible by using the length but it was slow too.

```
        window.setInterval(function(){ 
            jQuery("#vz").find('div').first().hide();

        }, 600);
```

Comment: So what is making it visible, why are you using a timeout?

Comment: where is your html?

Comment: Why not using a simple css rule for that? If you must use JS try to wrap your code in `$(document).ready()`

Comment: I have some code given to me. it generates 2 of the same html elements with the same id. All i want to do is hide one of them.

Comment: With the same ID? That is really bad html and can cause further problems

Comment: can you provide a css example please @empiric

Comment: @sarah [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/1g05gLnf/)

Comment: So when are they generated? And the only way you will not get a flash of content is to hide it with CSS to start.  Best solution, change whatever is making it twice....

Answer (score 6):

You can specify its `visibility` as `hidden` (In case you still want it to occupy space)

Or specify its `display` as `none` (In case you don't want it to occupy space)

Both of these should be done using CSS, so in your CSS file:

```
#vz {
    //This:
    visibility: hidden;
    //Or this:
    display: none;
}
```

And as a general role of thumb, initial style should be set in CSS and then you can animate/change it using JS or more CSS

Comment: I guess it should be something like: #vz div:first-child

Comment: Honestly the issue with the id should be fixed first before attempting to progress any further than this or it will end up biting back at the end of the day